# Docker Mysql image DB size increase?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing performance test of my code in Mac. Size of mysql (DB) docker image is small so I am not able to insert more than 2.2 million records. I need to insert around 1 million * 2 millon records.

How to increase db size of mysql image?

Comment: use an external volume

Comment: Hey increasing the volume  will increase memory size of DB?

Comment: yes..Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer given by @Scary Wombat in the comment, you can mount a volume inside your Docker container

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -v <local_path_of_your_volume>:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:<version>
```

Make sure you have all the size you need in `<local_path_of_your_volume>`.

See the Docs, [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: Make sure you have all the size you need in <local_path_of_your_volume> what does this mean??

and I want to increase DB memory in mysql docker image.
After adding volume and mounting volume to docker image what to do??

Comment: Make surer the size of your local volume is big enough for your need. MySQL will use it to store its data.